# Verification of proof that the empty set is well ordered

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

I felt a little weird (stupid) in writing this. I figure that I should just post it here.

> **Claim:** 
>   $(A,S)$ where $A=\emptyset$ 
>   is a linearly ordered set and a well-ordered set.

**Proof:**
$S$ is a binary relation in $A$. 
Then $S\subseteq A^2=\emptyset\implies S=\emptyset$. Then
\begin{align*}
aSb\text{ and }bSc\implies aSc&&\text{(1)}\\
aSb\implies bSa\text{ does not hold}&&\text{(2)}\\
a,b\in A\implies a=b\text{ or } aSb\text{ or } bSa&&\text{(3)}
\end{align*}
are all vacuously true. (1) proves $S$ is transitive in $A$.
(2) proves $S$ is asymmetric in $A$.
Therefore $S$ is a strict ordering of $A$.
(3) proves $(A,S)$ is a linearly ordered set.

$A\subseteq\emptyset\implies A=\emptyset$.
$A\subseteq\emptyset\text{ and } A\neq\emptyset$ is false. 
Therefore
\begin{align*}
A\subseteq\emptyset\text{ and } A\neq\emptyset
\implies A\text{ has a least element}
\end{align*}
is vacuously true. This proves $(A,S)$ is a well-ordered set.

Comment: Looks good to me. Its all vacuously true.

Comment: Any property of the form $\forall a_1,\ldots,a_N\in A\colon \phi(a_1,\ldots,a_N)$ is true for $A=\emptyset$.