# How to prove directly that the empty set is well ordered?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

I found a post concerning this question, but I cannot understand the proof given there of the fact I'm talking about.

The link is : [Verification of proof that the empty set is well ordered](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1778645/verification-of-proof-that-the-empty-set-is-well-ordered)

I think I can prove indirectly that the empty set is well ordered in the following way :

(1) suppose the empty set is not well ordered

(2) that is, suppose it is false that every non empty subset of the empty set has a first element

(3) it means there exists at least some set S such that

- S is a non empty subset of the empty set
- *and* S has no first element

(4) which requires the first conjunct  " S is a non empty subset of the empty set" to be true

(5) but this is impossible, for the empty set has only one subset, which is empty.

However , I cannot manage to give a *direct proof* of the same fact.

I cannot go further than this : 
(1) Let S be an arbitrary set 
(2) Assume it is true that :  S is a non empty subset of the empty set 
(3) Derive from this that : S has a first element. ... but how?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apply the [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-order) :

> $\emptyset$ is well-ordered **if** it has a total order and every non-empty subset of $\emptyset$ has a least element in this ordering.

It means :

> $\forall S (S \subseteq \emptyset \land S \ne \emptyset \to \ldots)$.

But the only subset of $\emptyset$ is $\emptyset$ itself.

Thus, $S \subseteq \emptyset \land S \ne \emptyset$ is False, and $(S \subseteq \emptyset \land S \ne \emptyset \to \ldots)$ is True, for every $S$.

Answer (score 4):

You can prove it by exhaustion:

- for every pair of distinct elements of the empty set, the elements are comparable. This is vacuously true, so that you have a total order (whatever the comparison rule);
- for every non-empty subset of the empty set, there is a least element. This is vacuously true.