# All subsets of well-ordered set are well-ordered - quibble or mistake?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Context: cheating on my homework like everybody else.

Let $S$ be a well-ordered set under a relation $R$.

Now there are books out there which say something like, for example:

> Clearly if $\le$ is a well-ordering on $E$ and if $A$ is a subset of $E$, the induced ordering $\le_A$ in $A$ is a well-ordering.

(Seth Warner's *Modern Algebra*, 1965, Chapter $\text {III}$: The Natural Numbers: $\S 14$: Orderings)

Similarly, in the context of class theory:

> If $A$ is well-ordered under $R$, so is every subclass of $A$.

(Smullyan and Fitting's *Set Theory and the Continuum Problem*, 2010, rev. ed. Chapter $4$: Superinduction, Well Ordering and Choice: Part $\text I$ -- Superinduction and Well Ordering: $\S 1$ Introduction to well ordering)

However, the definition of well-ordering is that:

> $R$ is a well-ordering on $A$ iff $R$ is a total ordering on $A$ such that every non-empty subset (subclasss) of $A$ has a smallest element with respect to $R$.

But the empty set needs to be excluded from these statements. That is, the "every subclass" statement in S&F, and the failure to specify the non-emptiness of $A$ in Warner, make these statements technically incorrect.

The empty set *cannot* be well-ordered under *any* relation, because it has no smallest element.

Three-part question:

- Is it just quibbling to insist on excluding the empty set?
- Is it actually a genuine *mistake* to exclude the empty set / class from the quoted sections?
- Is there some "fiddle" that I might have missed in my deep scanning of these works which allow the empty set to be considered well-ordered "vacuously" in some way?

Incidentally, to fend off possible comments, yes I know the empty class and the empty set are the same thing, this is a property arising from the axioms of whatever axiomatic system of set / class  theory you use.

Comment: On its face, I'd say the empty set was vacuously well ordered.  It is perfectly (if vacuously) true that every non-empty subset of the empty set has a least element.  See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3215746/how-to-prove-directly-that-the-empty-set-is-well-ordered#:~:text=%E2%88%85%20is%20well%2Dordered%20if,least%20element%20in%20this%20ordering.) for instance.

Comment: The empty set is well ordered in fact it's the first ordinal!! Also the axioms of well order are a relation (So a subset of pairs ) such that: forall $x$ $x\leq x$ for all $x,y$... etc. All the axioms or requirements are universal statements so they most certainly hold in the empty set.

Comment: "The empty set is not a non-empty subset of itself." Try keeping this fact in mind as you work through the definition of "well ordered", and you'll see that your claim is wrong. I think it's also a great exercise in realizing how unstated assumptions can sneak their way into one's thinking.

Comment: Why did I get a downvote, by the way? Is it because it's a stupid question?

Comment: The empty set is well ordered by the empty relation. It has no non-empty subsets, so it vacuously satisfies the conditions for being well-ordered.

Comment: "The empty set cannot be well-ordered under any relation, because it has no smallest element." But well-orderedness only requires every **nonempty** subset to have a least element. In order to go from "$X$ is well-ordered" to "$X$ has a least element," we need to know that $X$ is nonempty. There is no error in the cited texts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Say $A$ is well-ordered and $B\subset A$. To show that $B$ is well-ordered we need to show that if $C\subset B$ and $C\ne\emptyset$ then $C$ has a smallest element (true, since $C\subset A$). That definition includes the condition $C\ne\emptyset$; the condition $B\ne\emptyset$ doesn't come up anywhere. (If $B=\emptyset$ then $B$ has no non-empty subsets, and *hence* every nonempty subset of $B$ contains a smallest element...)

Comment: Also, if we assume $AC$, we can use the well ordering theorem, which shows that all sets are well orderable.

Comment: @MathGeek I don't see how AC helps - knowing that $B$ can be well ordered does not say that it _is_ well-ordered by the original order on $A$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich It does if $B$ is empty, because in that case there is only one binary relation on $B$. It does seem silly to use the well-ordering theorem to prove that the empty set can be well-ordered.